# Cannot send email from PHP via Mercury SMTP server: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I wrote a simple piece of code that should send email via Mercury server running on localhost. I checked that it can in fact send messages by going to File->Send mail message. It did successfully send email to my online mailbox.

However when I try to ask it to send email via telnet or from PHP script, I get this error for the same settings:

```
RCPT TO: <mymail@mymailprovider.com>
>> 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry.
```

This makes little sense to my, as the email is being sent from localhost. I have checked the checkbox to allow non-local mail, but this is quite worrying as it could be abused.

How to allow Mercury to send the email **without allowing it to send email from whoever can connect to my server**?

Comment: Since this was closed, presumably because the question was misunderstood, here's a answer: In the same dialog where you allow non-local mail, use Add restriction and only allow `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: So, is this a PHP problem, or an Apache problem after all?